# Confluent Kafka REST Proxy (Re-)joining group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am working on Confluent and Kafka REST Proxy. I have installed it on local Macbook. I am able to send (producer) and receive (consumer) messages using REST Proxy. Fine. But, sometimes it throws the following error message,

```
[2018-01-23 17:08:53,298] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=my_consumer] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:336)
```

I am not sure why is this error happening? When we receive this error message in console, unable to send and receive message.
I have checked this query, [Kafka consumer stuck in (Re-)joining group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891740/kafka-consumer-stuck-in-re-joining-group) 
but it doesn't help.

Please guide me how to fix this.

Comment: This isn't an error message, as noted by the `INFO` word, but consumer group rebalancing is considered a natural occurrence

Answer (score 0):

Late in the game but restarting zookeeper and brokers helped to resolve the issue.